# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' but it registers the user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, user-roles

I'm creating a way for Admin to create users and assign roles and even create new roles that will be available to choose from when creating users.  I get this error when creating a user

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'RoleName'.'
```

However, it will still create my user and use the role that I choose at the time of creation.  How can I either get rid of this error?  Why does it allow the creation if there's an error?

[image: User Role Creation]

Controller *Create User*:

```
public ActionResult CreateUser()
    {
        AssignRole();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateUser(FormCollection form)
    {
        var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));

        ////// OTHER CODE

        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = userName,
            Email = email,
            FirstName = firstName,
            LastName =lastName

        };

        var newUser = UserManager.Create(user/*, password*/);
        AssignRole(form);
        return View();
    }
```

Controller *Assign Role to User*:

```
public ActionResult AssignRole()
    {
        ViewBag.Roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem { Value = r.Name, Text = r.Name }).ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AssignRole(FormCollection form)
    {
        string usrname = form["txtuserName"];
        string rolname = form["RoleName"];

        var user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(usrname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, rolname);

        return View("Index");
    }
```

View *Create User*

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
    {
<div class="row">

    ////// OTHER CODE

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Select Role</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, "Select...")
    </div>
</div>
}
```

View *Assign Role*

```
<h2>Assign Role</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("AssignRole", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="txtuserName" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Select Role</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Roles, "Select...")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I'm in the Admin/CreateUser URL.  Controller = AdminController, Action = CreateUser, View = CreateUser.  The error happens in the CreateUser view under the Select Role section.

Comment: yes, 'ViewBag.Roles' is 'null'

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `AssignRole` within the `CreateUser` action on GET?

Comment: `yes, 'ViewBag.Roles' is 'null'` That is your bug then. You need to set it. Debug through the code. You aren't setting it. _You may be tempted to say you are setting it - but you are doing that on a previous web request. You aren't setting it on **this** request._

Comment: @Nkosi I was just messing around with the code, trying to see if anything worked.  I'm new to MVC and coding in general, so I figured it can't hurt to move things around and see if anything works.

Comment: The view bag is set per request. and seeing as you are not redirecting on the post request when the view displays again after post the view bad was not set, hence null.

Comment: `ViewBag` must assigned for each GET or POST request if both actions returning same view. Because `ViewBag.Roles` is null, `ViewData` searches something named `RoleName` and because it doesn't exist, the exception throws. I think better using DDLF if you have viewmodel properties: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleName, ViewBag.Roles as List<SelectListItem>, ...)`

Comment: `Why does it allow the creation if there's an error?` This is because the code that does the creation is in the action (i.e. early) while the code that throws the exception is in the view (i.e. later). The early code doesn't know the later code is going to throw an exception.

Comment: So all I did differently, just now, was change [return View();] to [return View("Index");] on the [CreateUser] action and it created the user and didn't get me an error, that was all I needed to do?  Also, I'm trying to figure out how you guys are making the code with a gray background, how are you doing that?  I didn't find it in the formatting section...

Comment: The `Index` view doesn't have corresponding DDL, hence it works. IMHO you can change return type of `AssignRole` to `List<SelectListItem>`, put `return db.Roles.Select(r => new SelectListItem { ... }).ToList()` and then use `ViewBag.Roles = AssignRole()`. It's unusual to have `ActionResult` methods called inside other `ActionResult`.